# Kartik's yii2-grid: Setting unknown property: kartik\grid\GridView::panel

Tags: gridview, yii2, panel

For the life of me, I'm unable to sort the following error out when using Kartik's yii2-grid:

**Setting unknown property: kartik\grid\GridView::panel**

My code is:

```php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use kartik\grid\GridView;

[...]

    <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'hover' => true,
        'persistResize' => true,
        'pager' => [
             'firstPageLabel' => Yii::t('app', 'Inicio'),
             'lastPageLabel' => Yii::t('app', 'Final'),
             'maxButtonCount' => Yii::$app->params['numBotones'],
          ],
        'panel ' => [
            'heading'=>'<h1>'.Html::encode(mb_strtoupper($this->title)).'</h1>', 
        ],
        'columns' => [
             ['class' => 'kartik\grid\SerialColumn'],

            [...]
```

However, `hover` and `persistResize` do work.

Also my `composer.json` contains:

```html
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.4.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-jui": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-grid": "@dev",
        "kartik-v/yii2-mpdf": "@dev",
        "kartik-v/yii2-widgets": "*",
        "2amigos/yii2-tinymce-widget" : "*",
        "sjaakp/yii2-illustrated-behavior": "*",
        "dektrium/yii2-user": "0.9.*@dev",
        "dektrium/yii2-rbac": "1.0.0-alpha@dev"
    },
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems you have a blank in the attribute   `'panel '`

```
 'panel ' => [
        'heading'=>'<h1>'.Html::encode(mb_strtoupper($this->title)).'</h1>', 
    ],
```

try remove it

```
   'panel' => [
        'heading'=>'<h1>'.Html::encode(mb_strtoupper($this->title)).'</h1>', 
    ],
```

Comment: Spot on man! I did search for any ",.;;......" on Earth but couldn't see that one. Nice. Thanks a lot.